# Help Solving a Logarithm Equation: $\log(2x) - \ln(x^2) = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Really basic. I have no idea what to do as I get stuck when I apply the change of base formula to $\ln(x^2)$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

$$\log(2x)-\ln(x^2) $$
$$= \log (2)+\log(x)-2\ln(x)$$
$$=\log(2)+\log(x)-2\frac{\log(x)}{\log(e)}\tag{1}$$
$$=\log(2)+(\log x)(1-\frac{2}{\log(e)}) = 3$$

I am sure you can solve it without my help from there.

In regards to (1), we have $\ln(x)=\log_e(x)=\frac{\log_{10}(x)}{\log_{10}(e)}$

Comment: In fact, $\;\log x^2=2\log|x|\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio That is true, but because of the log 2x term we have $x>0$, so it is ok to drop the absolute value bars

Comment: You are right. +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$$

$$m\log a=\log(a^m)$$

$$\log\dfrac ab=\log a-\log b$$ where all the logarithm remain defined

Comment: ... and $k=log(e^k)$ when $k$ is a constant, i.e., when there is no log on the horizon.

Comment: @JeanMarie In this context (OP's choice of notation) I think you should write $k=\ln(e^k)$ instead.

Comment: @Lovsovs yes and no, because there is an ambiguity ; I am not certain that the equation to be solved mixes $log$ and $ln$ : either 2 $log$s or 2 $ln$s. Could the OP say us ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It can be solved, even though it is mixed, as *Laplacian Fourier*'s answer shows.